# Problema com TouchableOpacity, margem negativa e Android - React Native

Tags: android, react, react-native, button, margin

Estou com um problema com o `TouchableOpacity` utilizando margem negativa para que diferentes `TouchableOpacities` fiquem um pouco em cima do outro *(vou postar imagem pra entenderem melhor)*. Esses botões estão sendo renderizados em uma `FlatList` e impressionantemente no iOS funciona bem, porém no Android fica bem estranho.

No Android quando eu clico em um botão na frente, é disparado o botão de trás.

Esse são os botões dentro da `FlatList`, cada botão fica em cima do outro.

| iOS | Android |
| --- | --- |
| [[image: Imagem mostrando a tela no dispositivo iOS] <sup>Clique na imagem para visualiza-la em seu tamanho original</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TggL.png) | [[image: Imagem mostrando a tela no dispositivo Android] <sup>Clique na imagem para visualiza-la em seu tamanho original</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DIQ9.png) |

**No Android**, quando eu cliquei no botão escrito `"Proposta 70"`, o botão escrito `"Proposta 78"` foi disparado.
O Android ignora totalmente os itens acima e sempre dispara o item mais abaixo, ou seja, o item que foi renderizado primeiro

O código da `FlatList`

```
<View style={styles.containerList}>
<FlatList
  data={proposalsList}
  keyExtractor={item => item.proposta_id}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
    <RenderItem
      item={item}
      index={index}
      isLoweredCard={
        openedCardIndex !== null && index === openedCardIndex + 1
      }
      changeOpenedCardIndex={changeOpenedCardIndex}
    />
  )}
  refreshing={loading}
  onRefresh={() => getProposalsAndNotifications()}
/>
```

o código dos botões (RenderItems)

```
<TouchableOpacity
  style={styles.container(index, isLoweredCard)}
  onPress={() => changeOpenedCardIndex(index)}
>
  <>
    <View
      style={[
        styles.lineContainer,
        { marginBottom: metrics.padding * 1.5 },
      ]}
    >
      <View
        style={{
          width: '50%',
        }}
      >
        <Text style={styles.proposalId}>
          {`Proposta ${item.proposta_id}`}
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.proposalDate}>
          {dayjs(item?.proposta_data_criacao).format('DD.MM.YYYY')}
        </Text>
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'flex-end',
        }}
      >
        <View style={styles.statusContainer}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: wp(4), fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
            <TypeStatus status={item?.proposta_status} />
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.lineContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.proposalDetailLabel}>Valor solicitado</Text>
      <Text style={styles.proposalDetailValue}>
        {formatCurrency(item?.proposta_valor_financiado)}
      </Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.lineContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.proposalDetailLabel}>Valor liberado</Text>
      <Text style={styles.proposalDetailValue}>
        {formatCurrency(item?.proposta_valor_financiado)}
      </Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.lineContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.proposalDetailLabel}>Parcelas</Text>
      <Text style={styles.proposalDetailValue}>
        {`${item?.proposta_valor_prazo}x`}
      </Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.lineContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.proposalDetailLabel}>Valor da parcela</Text>
      <Text style={styles.proposalDetailValue}>
        {formatCurrency(item?.proposta_valor_parcela)}
      </Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
      <Button
        onPress={goToDetails}
        title="Ver detalhes"
        titleStyle={styles.proposalButtonText}
        style={styles.button}
      />
    </View>
  </>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

E os estilos dos botões

```
import {
widthPercentageToDP as wp,
heightPercentageToDP as hp,
} from 'react-native-responsive-screen';

import { metrics, colors } from '../../../../constants';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: (index, isLoweredCard) => ({
 backgroundColor: `#00${index}F${index}C`,
 marginTop: !isLoweredCard && index !== 0 ? -wp(53) : metrics.padding,
 marginHorizontal: metrics.padding,
 alignContent: 'center',
 padding: metrics.padding,
 borderRadius: metrics.radius,
 zIndex: -(index + 999),
}),
lineContainer: {
 width: '100%',
 justifyContent: 'space-between',
 flexDirection: 'row',
 marginBottom: metrics.padding / 2,
},
statusContainer: {
 backgroundColor: colors.white,
 borderRadius: 20,
 width: '70%',
 paddingVertical: 3,
 alignItems: 'center',
 justifyContent: 'center',
},
proposalId: {
 color: colors.white,
 fontWeight: 'bold',
 fontSize: wp(4.5),
},
proposalDate: {
 color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
 fontWeight: 'bold',
 fontSize: wp(3.5),
},
proposalDetailLabel: {
 fontSize: wp(4),
 color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)',
},
proposalDetailValue: {
 fontSize: wp(4.5),
 color: colors.white,
 fontWeight: 'bold',
},
proposalButtonText: {
 color: colors.white,
 fontWeight: 'bold',
 fontSize: wp(4),
},
button: {
 borderRadius: metrics.radius,
 backgroundColor: '#002F6C',
 paddingHorizontal: metrics.padding * 3,
},
buttonContainer: {
 width: '100%',
 marginTop: metrics.padding,
 alignItems: 'center',
},
});

export default styles;
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Uma dica, quando tiver um problema com RN, tente reproduzí-lo em um [Snack](https://snack.expo.io) , isso facilitará a diminuir o problema à um [mcve] e também facilitará alguém de ajudar. Eu não analisei seu código inteiro, mas **talvez** o problema tenha a ver com você alterar o `z-index` para o iOS mas não alterar o `elevation` para o Android. O Android não faz uso do `z-index`